# RejectedExecutionException: ReactorDispatcher instance is closed. - Azure Event Hubs & Databricks Spark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I am trying to consume data from Azure Event Hubs with Databricks PySpark and write it in an ADLS sink. Somehow, the spark jobis not able to finish and gets aborted after running for 2 hours. The error is Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: ReactorDispatcher instance is closed.

here is a full error https://gist.github.com/kingindanord/a5f585c6ee7053c275c714d1b07c6538#file-spark_error-log

and here is my python script

```py
import json
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

KEY_VAULT_NAME="KEY_VAULT_NAME"
EVENT_HUBS_SECRET_NAME="EVENT_HUBS_SECRET_NAME"
EVENT_HUBS_CONSUMER_NAME="EVENT_HUBS_CONSUMER_NAME"
BATCH_START_DATE = datetime.strptime("2022-03-22 23:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
BATCH_END_DATE = datetime.strptime("2022-03-23 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
CONTAINER_NAME = "CONTAINER_NAME_AZ"
HUB_NAME = "HUB_NAME"
ROOT_FOLDER = "ROOT_FOLDER" 
SINK_URI = 'abfss://{CONTAINER_NAME}@.dfs.core.windows.net/{SINK_ROOT_FOLDER}'.format(CONTAINER_NAME=CONTAINER_NAME, SINK_ROOT_FOLDER=ROOT_FOLDER)

connection = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = KEY_VAULT_NAME, key = EVENT_HUBS_SECRET_NAME)
ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connection)
ehConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = EVENT_HUBS_CONSUMER_NAME

# Create the positions
startingEventPosition = {
  "offset": None,  
  "seqNo": -1,            #not in use
  "enqueuedTime": BATCH_START_DATE.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z"),
  "isInclusive": True
}

endingEventPosition = {
  "offset": None,
  "seqNo": -1,
  "enqueuedTime": BATCH_END_DATE.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z"),
  "isInclusive": True
}


ehConf["eventhubs.startingPosition"] = json.dumps(startingEventPosition)
ehConf["eventhubs.endingPosition"] = json.dumps(endingEventPosition)
ehConf["eventhubs.MaxEventsPerTrigger"] = 1000
ehConf["eventhubs.UseExclusiveReceiver"] = True

df = spark.read.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()

df2 = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))  \
    .withColumn("year", F.date_format(df["enqueuedTime"], "yyyy")) \
    .withColumn("month", F.date_format(df["enqueuedTime"], "MM")) \
    .withColumn("day", F.date_format(df["enqueuedTime"], "dd"))\
    .select("body", "year", "month", "day")

df2.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").mode("overwrite") \
      .format("delta") \
      .parquet(SINK_URI)
```

I am using a separate consumer group for this application. The Event hub has 3 partitions, Auto-inflate throughput units are enabled and it is set to 21 units.
Databricks Runtime Version: 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12) Worker type & Driver type are Standard_E16_v3 (128GB Memory, 16 Cores) Min workers: 1, Max workers, 3.

As you can see in the code, startingEventPosition and endingEventPosition are only one hour apart, so the size of data should be around 3 GB, I don't know why I am not able to consume them. Can you please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the 2 workarounds:

1. Set different Consumer Groups for each stream.
2. Restart databricks cluster and then try again.

Refer this [github link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/363)